# Magento 2 : When try to edit HTML content of CMS Page or Block, show success message but don't save content

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, cms-pages, page-builder, content

I am using Magento 2.4.6, I can't edit the content of CMS Page. When I change the HTML content of CMS Page and hit save button it gives the success message but doesn't actually save the content. This happens with chrome browser only and working fine with firefox.

I have tried following solution, which is not working for me.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37514#issuecomment-1576685269

Comment: Did you try in chrome incognito mode? Any error in browser console?

Comment: Did you fix it ? I encountered the same issue but only on latest Chome browser, but it is working fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

If you're experiencing an issue with editing CMS pages in Magento 2 specifically with Google Chrome, but not with Firefox, it could be related to browser compatibility or cache/cookie issues. Here are some steps you can take to troubleshoot and potentially resolve the problem:

- **Clear Browser Cache and Cookies:** Sometimes, outdated cache or cookies can cause issues with the functionality of a website. Try clearing your browser's cache and cookies and then attempt to edit the CMS page again.
- **Use Incognito Mode:** Open an incognito or private browsing window in Google Chrome and try editing the CMS page there. This will bypass any potential caching or cookie issues associated with your regular browsing session.
- **Check Console for Errors:** Open the developer tools in Google Chrome (F12 or Right-click > Inspect) and go to the Console tab. Look for any error messages that might indicate what's causing the issue. This could provide insights into any JavaScript errors or other problems.
- **Update Google Chrome:** Make sure you're using the latest version of Google Chrome. Outdated versions might have compatibility issues with certain websites or web applications.
- **Magento Cache:** Flush the cache in Magento. Sometimes, stale cache data can cause issues with editing content. You can do this by going to `System > Cache Management` in the Magento admin panel and clicking on `"Flush Magento Cache" and "Flush Cache Storage"`.

Comment: i  have already tried above steps but it doesn't work.